# Using boolean filter on Tire with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire on my Rails application, but the lack of documentation really frustrated me. I know the gem is "ReTire" but I need use him until I change to other gem.

I have a problem on filter like this simple query

`SELECT product
 FROM   products
 WHERE  (price = 20 OR productID = "XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3")
 AND  (price = 30)`

I already did it on Elastic Search string query:

```
GET /my_store/products/_search
{
 "query" : {
   "filtered" : { 
     "filter" : {
      "bool" : {
        "should" : [
          { "term" : {"price" : 20}}, 
          { "term" : {"productID" : "XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3"}} 
        ],
        "must" : {
          "term" : {"price" : 30} 
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

It's simple and worked! But I don't know how to make this on Tire structure. I already tried a lot of solutions, none worked.

I need a path to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following by any chance?

```
Tire.search 'products' do
  query do
    boolean do
      should   { string 'price:20' }
      should   { string 'productID:XHDK-A-1293-#fJ3' }
      must { string 'price:30' }
    end
  end
end
```